# how to use if statement from a makefile function?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I am reading configurations from .config file and I want to do some operation if a configuration is enabled. I have written following function but it is throwing error message "*/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting "then")*"

```
define parse_configs
    while read -r file; do \
        config=$$(echo $$file | grep -Po '(?<=(CONFIG_)).*(?==)'); \
        val=$$(echo $$file | grep -Po '(?<=(=)).*'); \
        $$(if $(findstring y, $$val), echo "do Ops", echo "No ops"); \
    done < .config;
endef
```

The problem is with if statement, other part of function is fine. Please let me know the mistake in the code. Thanks.

Comment: ugh there are so much better ways of doing this... :'( can you show your .config?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place -- Make isn't complaining about that particular `if` statement --   Make doesn't use `then`'s, so it wouldn't expect one.    You should post how you are calling the macro, as there may be something there that is causing your problem.    One thing from the code above though --  you're referencing `$$val` from withing `$(findstring y, $$val)`.   Because there's only one `$`, the `findstring` will expand when the macro body is first read, and therefore look for `y` in the string literal `$val` (which will return nothing every time).

Comment: Make will try to expand `$(findstring y, $$val)` before val is assigned.  How is this going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with the statement:

```
$$(if $(findstring y, $$val), echo "do Ops", echo "No ops");
```

is that is actually a [GNU Make if-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html),
calling the [GNU Make findstring-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html),
which you have written in the middle of a shell statement, and required (`$$`) that it be expanded by the shell, but it makes no sense to the shell.
It might as well be Javascript. Replace it with an appropriate *shell* if-statement, e.g.

```
while read -r file; do \
    config=$$(echo $$file | grep -Po '(?<=(CONFIG_)).*(?==)'); \
    val=$$(echo $$file | grep -Po '(?<=(=)).*'); \
    if [ -z $${val##*"y"*} ]; then echo "do Ops"; else echo "No ops"; fi; \
done < .config;
```